# How to get all users with permission on entity with Symfony ACL?

Tags: php, symfony, acl, symfony-3.2

I have a User who is able to EDIT multiple courses, how can I list all courses that a user can edit with the Symfony ACL? I've browsed through the docs and can only find how to check if the user can on that particular entity that's been loaded. I'd like to be able to put on the user's profile page a list of courses with each course name that the user can edit. If you can't is there an alternative? I've checked out voters and I don't think I can achieve what I'm trying to do with those as well.

For example, I assign a User an owner mask when they create a course.

```
$aclProvider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');
$objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($course);
$acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);

$tokenStorage = $this->get('security.token_storage');
$user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
$securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);

$acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
$aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
```

On the profile page I want to be able to do something like

```
$courses = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Course')
    ->findAllWhereUserCanEdit($user);
```

Comment: This question does not contain enough information to assist you. How do you determine whether a user can edit a course? How does the code for the page listing the courses look like, e.g. have you tried the naive approach of looping over all courses and filter out the ones the user is permitted to edit?

Comment: @dbrumann I've updated the question and that is what I'm trying to avoid as I know that desperately hurts the website's performance with all of the queries.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could provide an overview of how the acl table looks. I have a solution in mind using Doctrine DBAL QueryBuilder to create a query on the database, not the ORM-layer (entities) as the ACL-table is not mapped by an entity: In the ACL-table you have to look for user_id and permissions >= ? whatever the bitmask for edit is and then fetch all course-type object ids. Finally you have to join the resulting object id's with the courses table. You can use a ResultMapper to map the results from DBAL to entities.

Comment: I am using the default ACL that Symfony provides [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/acl.html). I have not changed the [database schema](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/acl_advanced.html#database-table-structure) at all as it is outlined in the docs. The only thing is that I am doing the same where I need to get all users that can edit a School and all users that can edit a District so I'm trying to do something that is reusable. Can I create a service class that takes the user and entity and use that to determine the query for the entity and bitmask? @dbrumann

Comment: Please stop assuming people know your project. You want us to solve your specific problem, so give us specific information. The table structure described in the documentation is not the schema. I have no way of knowing what is in those table. I either have to setup my own example project to find out or you provide those details to me. I won't do the former. You can use SequelPro or any other SQL tool to look at those tables. If you don't want us to see the actual data, setup a minimal example (one user, 2 courses one with, one without permission) and show us that. Then we can help you.

Comment: If you just want a general way how to solve this, I explained above. Take a user and a course find how they relate in the acl tables (I would start looking for their id's in `acl_entries`). Once you figured out how they relate, build a specific SQL query to produce the expected result, i.e. the object id's the user has access to. When you finished that you can start re-creating that query in a service or repository, probably using [Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) and then abstract away as far as you need.

Comment: OK, I'll probably do that. Thank you for that advice. @dbrumann

Comment: You can use [AclTreeBundle](https://github.com/AlmogBaku/AclTreeBundle) that have a helper class to filter result with some specific acl. you use it in entityRepository.